# Windows Server 2019 Kubernetes Worker Node Problem

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, hyper-v

I try to add a Kubernetes worker node on Windows Server 2019.I created a master node on Hyper-V virtual machine using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS sucessfully. On windows, firstly, I installed Docker, then I used the command below from the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/.

```
curl.exe -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/master/kubeadm/scripts/PrepareNode.ps1
.\PrepareNode.ps1 -KubernetesVersion v1.23.0
```

I got the below error from command line although I installed docker successfully and started docker service.

```
PrepareNode.ps1 : Docker service was not detected - please install start Docker before calling Pre
pareNode.ps1 with -ContainerRuntime Docker
At line:2 char:1
+ .\PrepareNode.ps1 -KubernetesVersion v1.23.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,PrepareNode.ps1
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Docker Engine works well, service started and I can run containers, but when I write this command on the command line, I get the below error:

```
docker -H npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine version
```

Output:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        2ee0c57608
 Built:             11/13/2019 08:00:16
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Comment: Have you installed docker correctly with that link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server#install-docker

Comment: cause if you see this error, then it can't be found in `//./pipe/docker_engine`. More: `if ($ContainerRuntime -eq "Docker") {
    if (-not(Test-Path "//./pipe/docker_engine")) {
        Write-Error "Docker service was not detected - please install start Docker before calling PrepareNode.ps1 with -ContainerRuntime Docker"
        exit 1
    }
}`

Comment: @Bazhikov I installed Docker correctly, the service is running. But this command does not recognize Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Launching Docker Desktop will fix this error and it will run docker daemon that is needed according to your error.

Here you can find [the guide](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#start-docker-desktop) on how to launch Docker Desktop

If the error still persists after launching, try to switch Docker daemon type with the following command in `cmd`:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 0):

after install docker, you should restart computer to find it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).